# Direct Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the equation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n^3+2}} $$

After simplifying the numbers and using the direct comparison method. You end up with the following.  So would you just take the limit and end up with 1?

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{3/2}}{n^{3/2}} $

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "simplifying the numbers?"

Comment: if I use the direct comparison test I get n * sqrt(n+1) / sqrt(n^3 +2) can be compared to n sqrt(n) / sqrt(n^3).  If you multiply them out on the top you get n^3/2 and on the bottom you end up with 1/n^3/2.

Comment: You have the right idea; since the absolute values of the terms approach 1, not 0, the series diverges by the nth-term test for divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n$$ must hold
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$$ and $$a_n$$ must monotonously decreasing then your series is convergent

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you cannot use direct comparison on series that have both negative and positive terms. So unfortunately that isn't the route to an answer.

However, you've noticed the important aspect. If you notice that the limit of the terms is not zero (and in particular alternates between $1$ and $-1$), then you *can* answer your question.